# Passing data with POST with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to POST some data to another page with AJAX but no info is going, i'm trying to pass the values of two SELECT (Dropdown menus).

My AJAX code is the following:

```
  $('#CreateHTMLReport').click(function()
{

   var DeLista = document.getElementById('ClienteDeLista').value;
   var AteLista = document.getElementById('ClienteParaLista').value;
   $.ajax(
    {
        url: "main.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{ DeLista : DeLista , AteLista : AteLista },
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.location = 'phppage.php';
        }
    });
});
```

Once I click the button with ID **CreateHTMLReport** it runs the code above, but it's not sending the variables to my `phppage.php`

I'm getting the variables like this:

```
$t1 = $_POST['DeLista'];
$t2 = $_POST['ParaLista'];
echo $t1;
echo $t2;
```

And got this error: `Notice: Undefined index: DeLista in...`

Can someone help me passing the values, I really need to be made like this because I have two buttons, they are not inside one form, and when I click one of them it should redirect to one page and the other one to another page, that's why I can't use the same form to both, I think. I would be great if someone can help me with this, on how to POST those two values `DeLista` and `ParaLista`.

**EDIT**

This is my `main.php`

```
$('#CreateHTMLReport').on('click',function() {
   $.ajax({
        // MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THIS PAGE CREATED!!
        url: "main.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            // You may as well use jQuery method for fetching values
            DeLista : $('#ClienteDeLista').val(),
            AteLista : $('#ClienteParaLista').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // Use this to redirect on success, this won't get your post
            // because you are sending the post to "main.php"
             window.location = 'phppage.php';

            // This should write whatever you have sent to "main.php"
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And my `phppage.php`

```
if(!empty($_POST['DeLista'])) {
    $t1 = $_POST['DeLista'];
    # You should be retrieving "AteLista" not "ParaLista"
    $t2 = $_POST['AteLista'];
    echo $t1.$t2;
    # Stop so you don't write the default text.
    exit;
}
echo "Nothing sent!";
```

And I'm still getting "Nothing Sent".

Comment: Try some basic debugging here.  var_dump the `$_POST` var to see what you're actually getting

Comment: @WillardSolutions when I do some 'alert(DeLista);' for example I get the result, I just have no clue why it is not passing to my other php page.

Comment: `url: "main.php",` " it's not sending the variables to my phppage.php".  Well, you're telling it to post to `main.php`, not `phppage.php`.

Comment: @PatrickQ changed the main.php to phppage.php but still getting the same error

Comment: You're probably still doing `window.location = 'phppage.php';`, right?  There's no need for that.  Also, you have `AteLista` in your `data` object, but `$_POST['ParaLista']` in your PHP.  One of those needs to change so that they match.  Finally, whatever you `echo` on the PHP page will become the contents of the `data` variable in your `success` callback.  I highly recommend that you spend some time learning how ajax works.

Comment: would adding `content-type:"application/json"` in the ajax body work?

Comment: Do a var_dump() in your PHP, not your JS....

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a destination confusion and you are not retrieving what you are sending in terms of keys. You have two different destinations in your script. You have `main.php` which is where the Ajax is sending the post/data to, then you have `phppage.php` where your success is redirecting to but this is where you are seemingly trying to get the post values from.

**/main.php**

```
// I would use the .on() instead of .click() 
$('#CreateHTMLReport').on('click',function() {
   $.ajax({
        // MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THIS PAGE CREATED!!
        url: "phppage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            // You may as well use jQuery method for fetching values
            DeLista : $('#ClienteDeLista').val(),
            AteLista : $('#ClienteParaLista').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // This should write whatever you have sent to "main.php"
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**/phppage.php**

```
<?php
# It is prudent to at least check here
if(!empty($_POST['DeLista'])) {
    $t1 = $_POST['DeLista'];
    # You should be retrieving "AteLista" not "ParaLista"
    $t2 = $_POST['AteLista'];
    echo $t1.$t2;
    # Stop so you don't write the default text.
    exit;
}
# Write a default message for testing
echo "Nothing sent!";
```

Comment: I have two pages, the main.php where I have the AJAX, and then I need to send it to phppage.php, and still not working even if I place like this: url: "phppage.php" or url: "main.php"

Comment: Alright, so from your comment, I have edited the ajax which is now correct (from a technical standpoint). You need to post your form in order to see how you are naming things and what exactly these elements are you've labelled in your javascript.

Comment: I see from your edit, you are getting `Nothing sent!` which means you have the ajax working, so likely you don't have your form set up properly because `$_POST['DeLista']` is being sent empty, so `$('#ClienteDeLista').val()` is not getting a value.

Answer (score -1):

You have to urlencode the data and send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.